# Why is the migration generator creating temporary tables?

Tags: sqlite, typeorm

When I run the migration generator it creates a table, plus a temporary table, then performs an insert into the temporary table of a select of all first table columns, deletes the first table and and renames the temporary table to the same name of the first.

I must be doing something wrong because none of the examples I have seen show this in the migration output.

This is my ormconfig.json

```
{
  "type": "sqlite",
  "database": "./db/database.sqlite",
  "synchronize": false,
  "migrationsRun": false,
  "logging": false,
  "entities": ["lib/entity/**/*.js"],
  "migrations": ["lib/migration/**/*.js"],
  "subscribers": ["lib/subscriber/**/*.js"],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
    "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
    "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
  }
}
```

Comment: I noticed this behavior when using the Sqlite driver if I add a column to a table. Instead of running `ALTER TABLE` to add the column, it creates a new temporary table with the extra column, copies all data from the old table, drops the old table, then renames the temporary table. My guess is this is due to Sqlite not having the same SQL compatibility as MySQL or Postgres